# How to create listview in android? How many methods to be used?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to know about basics to create ListView. 
How many methods to use the create ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial should guide you

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Answer (score 2):

Hey i too new to android, there are two different ways to implement listview. 1) we can assign listview by giving values in main.xml.

```
 <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


public class ListviewExample extends Activity
{
private ListView lv1;
private String lv_arr[]={"Android","iPhone","BlackBerry","AndroidPeople"};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
// By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
}
}
```

2) In second method, we can assign values in string.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
<string-array name="countries_array">
    <item>Bahrain</item>
    <item>Bangladesh</item>
    <item>Barbados</item>
    <item>Belarus</item>
    <item>Belgium</item>
    <item>Belize</item>
    <item>Benin</item>
   </string-array>
   </resources>

String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countries));
```

Comment: if you got the answer, do vote. we are not here to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ApiDemos sample code, particularly the group of examples dealing with list views (follow the [Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html) link and scroll down).